# Find First and Second Occurrence of Value Across Two Columns by Group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like the one below. It is sorted by Ref1 and Seq.

| Ref1 | EvnNo | P1 | P2 | Seq | PP1 | PP2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaaa | 0 | xxx | yyy | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| aaaa | 0 | xxx | yyy | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| aaaa | 0 | xxx | yyy | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| aaaa | 0 | xxx | yyy | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| aaaa | 1 | xxx | yyy | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| aaaa | 1 | xxx | yyy | 6 | 1 | 0 |
| aaaa | 1 | xxx | yyy | 7 | 1 | 0 |
| aaaa | 1 | xxx | yyy | 8 | 0 | 1 |
| bbbb | 0 | xxx | yyy | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| bbbb | 0 | xxx | yyy | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| bbbb | 0 | xxx | yyy | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| bbbb | 0 | xxx | yyy | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| bbbb | 1 | xxx | yyy | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| bbbb | 1 | xxx | yyy | 6 | 0 | 0 |
| bbbb | 1 | xxx | yyy | 7 | 1 | 0 |
| bbbb | 1 | xxx | yyy | 8 | 0 | 1 |

I am trying to work out how to do two things:

1. count the first occurrences of a 1 in either PP1 or PP2 grouped by Ref1 and EvNo. There may be no occurrences or there may be multiple occurrences but there will never be a 1 in both columns on the same row.
2. after the first occurrence (if any) count if there is a 1 in the other of PP1 or PP2 in the same group. Eg if the first 1 in a group was in PP1 count if the next occurrence of 1 is in PP2. If the next 1 is also in PP1 it should not be counted. There may be no further occurrences of a 1 in either column.

Output:

| P1 First Occ | P2 First Occ | P1 Second Occ | P2 Second Occ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: Where are the Ref1/EvnNo in the output? Is it complete?

Comment: Hello mozway, the output is just the counts. They don't need to be in a df, that's just how I did it to show the result I'm trying to get

Comment: Sorry, the logic is still unclear, can you break down the numbers 2/1/0/1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the result by applying a separate function to groups of the dataframe, turning the result into a new dataframe and summarizing it.

In the function the main trick is to use `np.where`. I used it on a sum of columns `PP1` and `PP2` to find just any occurences, and then checked which column provided the occurence just by checking if the value in `PP1` column is `1` (if yes - then the occurence is in `PP1`, if not - in `PP2`, as you said that the occurences can not happen simultaneously).

Although, I am not sure why your output doesn't have `1` for `P1 Second Occ`, because the first group (`Ref1 == "aaaa" and EvnNo == 0`) shows exactly that, if I understood the question correctly.

```
import numpy as np

def count_occurences(group):
    result = [0] * 4

    occurences = np.where(group.sum(axis=1) == 1)[0]
    
    # track first occurence
    if len(occurences) > 0 and group.iloc[occurences[0]]["PP1"] == 1:
        result[0] += 1
    elif len(occurences) > 0:
        result[1] += 1
    
    # track second occurence
    if len(occurences) > 1 and group.iloc[occurences[1]]["PP1"] == 1:
        if result[0] != 1:
            result[2] += 1
    elif len(occurences) > 1:
        if result[1] != 1:
            result[3] += 1
        
    return result


occurences_df = pd.DataFrame(
    df \
        .groupby(["Ref1", "EvnNo"]) \
        [["PP1", "PP2"]] \
        .apply(count_occurences) \
        .to_list(),
    columns = ["P1 First Occ", "P2 First Occ", "P1 Second Occ", "P2 Second Occ"]
)

print(occurences_df.sum())
```

Output:

```
P1 First Occ     2
P2 First Occ     1
P1 Second Occ    1
P2 Second Occ    1
```

Comment: This is brilliant Maria. Much appreciated!